# FormArray value empty despite controls containing FormControls

Tags: angular, observable, angular-material2, formarray, angular-cdk

**Update:**

I'm using a `MatDataTable` to show the `FormArray` contents with a custom `DataSource` and the problem appears to be with the `DataSource.connect()` function. I'm merging 2 observables to slice the data according to the paginator page configuration as follows:

```
export class DimensionDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  renderedData: BuildingDimension[] = [];

  constructor(
    private _dimensions: FormArray,
    private _paginator: MatPaginator,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<BuildingDimension[]> {
    // Listen for any changes in the base data or pagination
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._dimensions.valueChanges,
      this._paginator.page,
    ];

    return Observable
      .merge(...displayDataChanges)
      .map(() => {
        // Test for empty data set
        if (!this._dimensions.value) {
          return [];
        }

        // Grab the page's slice of the sorted data.
        const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
        this.renderedData = this._dimensions.value.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);

        // Set paginator length
        this._paginator.length = this._dimensions.value.length;

        return this.renderedData;
      });
  }

  disconnect() { }

}
```

I've used the same approach successfully elsewhere in my app but here it doesn't work.

What I've discovered while experimenting in Stackblitz is the following. If the paginator page size is set to 5, then the first 5 items added won't appear in the `FormArray` value, however, the 6th will. Check it out here & note the console debug logs. Also, note what happens when you change any of the paginator controls with more than 5 items added:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdrjqy

**Original Question:**

How is it possible for a `FormArray` with a `FormGroup` in its `controls` array, not have a value? I have an identical set up in 2 parts of my app but for some reason, in one part, the value is an empty array... I've spent hours on this and can't for the life of me replicate it, fix it or find any documentation that explains what is going on here!

Here is a screenshot of a console log of the `FormArray`:

[image: console log]

Comment: Create a StackBlitz example and show what exactly problem is

Comment: @Yerkon I've tried but I haven't been able to replicate the problem which is very frustrating! I guess I was wondering if this scenario was meant to be possible and if so why/how...

Comment: @Yerkon I've managed to recreate the problem in stackblitz. See updated question

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @yurzui Facepalm!! I can't believe a 'p' cost me half a day of work... Actually, there were a few other things at play here but that was the main cause of the weird paginator behavior. Thanks for spotting that! You can add an answer if you like.

Comment: I have faced the same issue, the problem is you need to use `formArray.push` not `formArray.controls.push`